# How to shallow copy a Javascript object while preserving getters/setters?

Tags: javascript

Background (why `Object.update()` or `jQuery.extend()` is not a solution, and why this is not a duplicate of the other how-to-copy-a-javascript-object questions):
This version of copy, using a for-loop

```
function copy_obj(obj) {
    var copy = {};
    for (var attr in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

only copies the values of the attributes (as does `Object.update()`), and fails on an object like:

```
var myobj = {
    _fname: 'fname',
    _lname: 'lname',
    get fullname() { return this._fname + ' ' + this._lname; },
    set fullname(v) { this._fname = v; }
};
```

i.e.

```
myobj.fullname === 'fname lname'  // true
myobj.fullname = 'Anton'
myobj.fullname === 'Anton lname'  // true
```

while

```
var mycopy = copy_obj(myobj);
mycopy.fullname === 'fname lname'  // true
mycopy.fullname = 'Anton'
mycopy.fullname === 'Anton'  // oops!
```

Question: I've figured out that I need to use getOwnPropertyNames/Descriptor to get/set the descriptors, but I haven't found any simple way to determine if something is just a plain value that can be copied directly -- what goes into the if-statement:

```
function copy_obj2(obj) {
    var mycopy = {};
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function (prop) {
        var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
        if (/* descriptor is a plain value */) {
            mycopy[prop] = obj[prop];
        } else {
            Object.defineProperty(mycopy, prop, descriptor);
        }
    });
    return mycopy;
}
```

(I'm only interested in copying object-like values, not Arrays or other basic types).

Comment: Why would you care what kind of descriptor it is? `Object.defineProperty` can be used to create data properties just as well.

Comment: Hint: "plain" descriptors have `writable` and `value` fields, no `get` or `set` ones. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors#Description

Comment: Isn't a data descriptor/property much more overhead than a plain value?

Comment: In addition to having a value, not having get/set, do I not need to check enumerable/writable/configurable too?

Comment: What kind of overhead are you talking about? You already got the descriptor anyway, so just use it. There's no point in branching and using the assignment operator instead in only those cases where it would lead to just the same result as `Object.defineProperty(mycopy, prop, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop));`

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that `Object.defineProperty(mycopy, prop, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop))` is exactly equivalent to `mycopy[prop] = obj[prop]` when `obj[prop]` is not a getter/setter. I'm assuming that is what you're saying, correct?

Comment: …and when it's enumerable, writable and configurable, and the target doesn't inherit a setter already; but I supposed that you wanted to copy those other attributes as well when you want to copy getters/setters as they are.

Comment: Are you sure you need a copy? Sometimes inheriting from the object is sufficient. And why does the `var mycopy = copy_obj(myobj);` not get used in your example? You're accessing `myobj` after making the copy, so I don't know what you're trying to say there.

Comment: @squint I fixed the missing use of `mycopy`, thanks for noticing. (ps: I do need a copy in this case, but you're correct, inheritance will often work -- even though it's not the first thing that comes to mind when you "just" want a copy of an object..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the type of descriptor; whether it's a data-type descriptor or an accessor-type descriptor, you can just use it as is to create the property on the target object.

```
function copy_obj2(obj) {
    var mycopy = {};
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function (prop) {
        var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
        Object.defineProperty(mycopy, prop, descriptor);
    });
    return mycopy;
}
```

But you could also use `getOwnPropertyDescriptors`, with `defineProperties`:

```
function copy_obj2(obj) {
  return Object.defineProperties({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
}
```

If you also want to include the prototype in the clone, then:

```
function copy_obj2(obj) {
  return Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj),  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
}
```

However, `getOwnPropertyDescriptors` is not available in IE. A polyfill is suggested [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-getownpropertydescriptors#user-content-proposed-solution).

Comment: `getOwnPropertyDescriptors` is pretty recent on Chrome/FF too so I can probably not use it without adding a polyfill..